# Sync-TtmCdEnvironment / Enable-TtmCdEnvironment {"error":"invalid_grant"} Error

Tags: topology-manager, discovery-service, cis

Working on a Database refresh in SDL Tridion Sites 8.5

**Prework**

1. Import Databases
2. CM DB, Broker DB's, Discovery DB's
3. Bring down all containers for CIS
4. Modify Dockerfile (ie
   Dockerfile.live.discovery) to updated (target) SQL Server DB credentials
5. Bring back up all CIS

**TopMan**

1. Get-TtmCdEnvironment
2. `Disable-TtmCdEnvironment -Id Preview_CdEnvId`
3. Export TopMan CdStructure
4. *Manually updated json with the Target Discovery endpoints*
5. Import TopMan CdStructure
6. Set-TtmCmEnvironment
7. `Enable-TtmCdEnvironment -Id Preview_CdEnvId` - this is where I get this error
8. `Sync-ttmCdEnvirnonment` - get pretty much same error. Which confirms (to myself) I am doing something wrong here..

Then try to run `Sync-TtmCdEnvironment` and pass *any* CdEnvId's (i.e. Preview_CdEnvId), I get `OAuth` Error below, `"error":"invalid_grant"}`

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> Sync-TtmCdEnvironment
cmdlet Sync-TtmCdEnvironment at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
(Type !? for Help.)
Id: !?
ID of the CdEnvironment
Id: Preview_CdEnvId
Sync-TtmCdEnvironment : Unable to synchronize item of type 'CdEnvironmentData' with id 'Preview_CdEnvId'.
One or more errors occurred.
An error occurred while processing this request.
{"error":"invalid_grant"}
At line:1 char:1
+ Sync-TtmCdEnvironment
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Tridion.Topolog...ironmentCommand:SyncEnvironmentCommand) [Sync-TtmCdEnvironment], DataServiceException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : Tridion.TopologyManager.Automation.Cmdlets.SyncEnvironmentCommand
```

However, I validate in Postman and everything looks good.

> http://server.com:8082/discovery.svc

```
<service xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2007/app" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:metadata="http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/metadata" xmlns:base="http://server.com:8182/discovery.svc" xmlns:context="http://server.com:8182/discovery.svc/$metadata">
<workspace>
    <atom:title>TridionWebDiscovery</atom:title>
    <collection href="WebApplications">
        <atom:title>WebApplications</atom:title>
    </collection>
    <collection href="PublicationMappings">
        <atom:title>PublicationMappings</atom:title>
    </collection>
    <metadata:singleton href="Environment">
        <atom:title>Environment</atom:title>
    </metadata:singleton>
</workspace>
```

Question - is there somewhere in the `Sync-TtmCdEnvironment` cmdlet that I can pass in the OAuth credentials or how does this work exactly?

---

**UPDATE I** - Same thing happens with `Enable-TtmCdEnvironment`

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> Enable-TtmCdEnvironment -Id Preview_CdEnvId
Enable-TtmCdEnvironment : One or more errors occurred.
Authorization failed while attempting to communicate with CD Discovery Service 'http://server.com:8182/discovery.svc'. Please make sure the proper credentials have been configured in the CD Environment 'Preview_CdEnvId'.
An error occurred while processing this request.
{"error":"invalid_grant"}
At line:1 char:1
+ Enable-TtmCdEnvironment -Id Preview_CdEnvId
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Tridion.Topolog...ironmentCommand:EnableCdEnvironmentCommand) [Enable-TtmCdEnvironment], DataServiceException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : Tridion.TopologyManager.Automation.Cmdlets.EnableCdEnvironmentCommand
```

---

**UPDATE II** - for Velmurugan answer below.

```
EnvironmentPurpose   : Preview
DiscoveryEndpointUrl : http://server.<hidden>.com:8182/discovery.svc
Credentials          : "AuthenticationType":"OAuth", "ClientId":"cmuser", "ClientSecret":"********"
IsOffline            : True
ScopedRepositoryKeys : {}
Id                   : Preview_CdEnvId
ExtensionProperties  : {}
```

---

**UPDATE Part III**

Riddle me this - I am able to `Set-TtmCdEnvironment` successfully with DS  - So I am able to validate that it is indeed able authenticate with `OAuth` from same environment, same env purpose, etc., but when I try to enable or synch environment, returns same OAuth response as it is invalid. `{"error":"invalid_grant"}`

[image]

Comment: Is it your setup has multiple Topology Manager instances running side by side?

Comment: working on db refresh to lower environment, not scaled out environment. So I need to export/import `TopMan` but just trying to figure out a data refresh would work..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CMEnvironmentId needs to be the same across all scaled out instances. Even if their roles are different like the coreservice, publisher, workflow agent. The CMEnvironmentId is kept the same using the database name and DB server name.

Double check the **TRIDION_CM_ENVIRONMENT_ID** and **Get-TtmCmEnvironment** cmdlet to check the CoreServiceCredentials details and modify by **Set-TtmCmEnvironment**

Also double check your DiscoveryEndpointUrl Credentials are used correctly **cmuser** and credentials by **Get-TtmCdEnvironment** cmdlet

I hope it helps.

Comment: I have the updated my question with the `Get-TtmCdEnvironment` response for `Preview_CdEnvId` - which is a CdEnvId I chose to do this.. same behaviour for all exist. I am just isolating.

Comment: Try with verbose enabled to capture the error details by running this cmdlet **Enable-TtmCdEnvironment -Verbose -Id Preview_CdEnvId** and then also once again double check the discovery service config **cd_ambient_conf.xml** for **cmuser** credentials, because while setting with Set-TtmCmEnvironment cmdlets it's really not validating only validating by running the Enable-TtmCdEnvironment

Comment: Thanks. I was able to find error in the `cis` services.. fixed and all cmdlts work and able to publish!! woohoo!